# Confused over equations from a book dealing with analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

$\eqalign{
  & {\text{Extract from Visual Complex Functions an introduction }}  \cr 
  & {\text{with Phase portraits Wegert published by Birkhauser}} \cr} $
$\eqalign{
  & {\text{Let }}f(z) = {a_0} + {a_1}z + {a_2}{z^2} + ... + {a_n}{z^n}{\text{ be a polynomial of degree at most n}}{\rm{.}}  \cr 
  & \omega {\text{ be the principle (n + 1)th root of unity}}{\rm{.}}  \cr 
  & \omega : = \cos \left( {2\pi /(n + 1)} \right) + i\sin \left( {2\pi /(n + 1)} \right)  \cr 
  & {a_k} = {\textstyle{1 \over {n + 1}}}\sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {{\omega ^{ - jk}}} f({\omega ^j}),k = 0,1,...,n.  \cr 
  & 1 + {\omega ^2} + {\omega ^3} + ... + {\omega ^n} = {\textstyle{{{\omega ^{n + 1}} - 1} \over {\omega  - 1}}} = 0  \cr 
  & f({\omega ^j}){\omega ^{ - jk}} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {{a_i}} {\omega ^{j(i - k)}} = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^n {{a_i}} {({\omega ^{i - k}})^j}{\text{ for }}j = 0,..,n  \cr 
  & {\text{all the terms cancel apart from when }}i = k,{\text{in which case}}  \cr 
  & {({\omega ^{i - k}})^j} = 1{\text{ and therefore the sum equals}}  \cr 
  & (n + 1){a_k} \cr} $

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lYII.png

Until I master enough TeX starting as soon as I do this I have to resort to a picture. How does the highlighted relate to below equations? The sum equals zero but the a's get in the way. So how does the cancellation happen for each of the n+1 equations when j runs thru from 0 to n?

Comment: ...is there any reason to the huge blocks of... text(?) in the source? It just makes trying to edit this harder, and looking at the preview of this post very confusing.

Comment: No sorry the only reason is my total lack of ability to handle the complex editor for equations. Please accept my apology. I really wish I did not need to learn a new language just to ask  math questions.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt In case it's not clear from his answer: Note the "MathType" at the start of those blocks of text. He's using a point&click equation editor in MS Word...

Comment: @Megamatics MathType can export Latex to the clipboard...

Comment: @Megamatics I kept using MathType for years after everyone else in the department was using TeX. That was a mistake. TeX is not that hard - you can do a lot after learning just the absolute basics. And sure enough, as my friends predicted, once I knew just a little bit of TeX I found it much easier, or at least faster, more efficient/"productive". Compare (i) type "\int_0^1" to (ii) Find the mouse, find the integral symbol, click on it. Then click on one tiny box to enter the "0" and click on the other tiny box to enter the  "1"...

Comment: Yes I used mathtype 7. Mathtype seemed more user friendly and under options for cut/pasting functions specifically to this board/forum. Don't understand why so much formatting 'baggage' is generated for so little. I will try to learn the proper way and TeX. I was under the (obviously wrong) assumption that the forum uses LaTeX or is that a TeX variant?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I proposed an edit to remove all that text. However someone will need to approve it.

Answer (score 2):

Though you did not define the $a_i$, I assume they are the coefficients of $f$. I.e., $$f(z) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_iz^i$$

Now let $z = \omega^j$, for some $j$:

$$f(\omega^j) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i\omega^{ji}$$

Multiply this by $\omega^{-jk}$ for some $k$:

$$\begin{align}f(\omega^j)\omega^{-jk} &= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i\omega^{ji}\omega^{-jk}\\&= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i\omega^{ji-jk}\\&= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i\omega^{j(i-k)}\\&= \sum_{i=0}^n a_i(\omega^{i-k})^j\end{align}$$

So $k$, like $j$, is just an arbitrary fixed index value. I.e., this gives you a separate equation for each value of $k$.

---

To answer the question about why the everything cancels when $i \ne k$:

First, let me note that the book commits a cardinal sin of mathematics here. It uses the same symbol with two different meanings in the same context. $\omega$ is introduced in the Lemma statement as a specific $n+1$-st root of unity (the principle root - though any primitive root will work). But in the very opening line of the proof, it uses $\omega$ to represent *any* $n+1$-st root of unity other than $1$. This redefinition only applies to this one sentence. Elsewhere in the proof, it returns to the definition given in the lemma. Thus, the authors sow confusion on their audience. Let me restate it more appropriately:

> First of all we observe that for *any* $(n+1)$th root of unity $\alpha$ with $\alpha \ne 1$,$$1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3+ ... +\alpha^n = \frac{\alpha^{n + 1} - 1}{\alpha - 1} = 0$$

From your highlighting and added question, it seems like you may be confused about the purpose of this equation. The author is proving $1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3+ ... +\alpha^n = 0$. The purpose of the highlighted portion is exactly to accomplish this calculation. The expression in the middle is equal to both sides. The left equation can be proven by simplifying $(1+\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3+ ... +\alpha^n)(\alpha - 1)$, then dividing $(\alpha - 1)$ back out.
The right equation follows because $\alpha^{n+1} = 1$ by definition, and $\alpha \ne 1$ by hypothesis.

So now, why do all the terms $a_i(\omega^{i-k})^j$ with $i\ne k$ cancel out? Because what the author is talking about is the formula he is proving in the lemma:

$$a_k = \frac 1{n + 1}\sum_{j = 0}^n \omega^{-jk}f(\omega^j)$$ for all $k = 0,1,...,n$. Plug in the formula for $\omega^{-jk}f(\omega^j)$ developed above, then exchange the summations by $i$ and $j$:

$$a_k = \frac 1{n + 1}\sum_{j = 0}^n \omega^{-jk}f(\omega^j)\\
= \frac 1{n + 1}\sum_{j = 0}^n\sum_{i=0}^n a_i(\omega^{i-k})^j\\
= \frac 1{n + 1}\sum_{i = 0}^n a_i\left[\sum_{j=0}^n (\omega^{i-k})^j\right]$$

Now when $i\ne k, \omega^{i-k}$ is an $n+1$-st root of unity, but is not $1$ [do you see why?]. So letting $\alpha = \omega^{i-k}$, we can apply the other formula to get that $\sum_{j=0}^n (\alpha)^j = 0$.

Whereas when $i = k, \omega^{i-k} = 1$, so $\sum_{j=0}^n (\omega^{i-k})^j = \sum_{j=0}^n 1 = n+1$.

Comment: As a side note do you  (or is it necessary for me to) type the TeX directly in or do you use an editor then copy/past here? Do I need to learn everything at once?

Comment: Can you show how and why they all cancel apart from those where k=i?

Comment: @Megamatics - I enter my TeX directly. [This tutorial is really helpful](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Even the best editors produce inferior results to hand-crafting, and are often harder to use, once you get the basics of mathjax down. A tip: If you see something in a formula and want to know how it was done, you can right-click on the formula and select "Show Math As >> TeX Commands" to see the TeX code.

Comment: You hadn't asked about the cancellation originally, so I had assumed you knew that part. I don't have the time to provide a full answer now, but will do so later. But recall that in the formula you are proving, $j$ is summed over. If you exchange the sums on $i$ and $j$, when $i \ne k$, you get $a_i$ times a sum over powers of roots, like the one that was shown to be $0$.

Comment: @Megamatics - I've added a full explanation of why the $i\ne k$ terms cancel to my answer.

Comment: Your clear exposition was very helpful

Comment: That is just commutivity and associativity of addition. Since both sums are finite, it is just a matter of rearranging the order of summation. (With infinite sums, there are also concerns about convergence that have to be addressed. But with finite sums, rearranging is always possible.)